# 15.10: WiFi blocked/no resume after suspend/no bright hotkeys after upgrade

Tags: wireless, brightness, function-keys

I have a:

```
Samsung Laptop model NP270E4E-K0ACL
Intel Sandy Bridge Mobile Graphics Card
Atheros AR9485 Wireless
```

After a clean installation of Ubuntu 15.10 using an ISO burned image (kernel `4.2.0-16-generic`), all system worked OK, no problems, no proprietary drivers required... all OK and ready to use. But after of `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` after installation, I have four problems (upgraded to kernel `4.2.0-35-generic`).

- WiFi is hard blocked, and it's impossible to enable (enable/disable hotkey is Fn+F12, no physical switch).
- Resume after suspend doesn't work, black screen on resume.
- Screen output control hotkey doesn't work (enable/disable hotkey is Fn+F4)
- Bright screen controls doesn't work, I can change brightness with the Ubuntu Control Panel slider, but hotkeys doesn't work (Fn+F2 and Fn+F3)

I tried every solution founded in Google: using `rfkill`, `ifup wlan0`, selecting in grub the previous kernel, uninstalling the new kernel, resetting BIOS/UEFI, changing WiFi internal minicard, external USB wifi adapter (WiFi works, if I remove the internal minicard), adding options in modules load, installing Intel provided driver, etc. But nothing works.

`xev` doesn't recognizes the hotkeys for change bright (Fn+F2 and Fn+F3), control screen output (Fn+F4) and enable/disable WiFi (Fn+F11).
All another hotkeys works OK and keypresses are detected by xev: Enable/disable touchpad (Fn+F5) and Mute/Volume control (Fn+F6, Fn+F7 and Fn+F8)
Fn+F11 is Fan Control, never worked.

This is the second clean Ubuntu 15.10 installation and the second upgrade after installation and the problem is the same after upgrade Ubuntu 15.10
What can I do?

Thanks in advance !

(Posted in Ubuntuforums 3 with no answer http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2320615)

Comment: I think you will have much better luck if you ask each question separately. If you'd care to edit your question to *only* address the wireless issue, I will be very happy to help.

Comment: Solved! It was a BIOS error from Samsung. The problem was solved according to next steps. 1) Enter to BIOS/UEFI from Windows 8 installation disk. 2) On the BIOS/UEFI set hard disk to "normal" (not AHCI) 3) Install Windows 8 (no blue screen!) 4) Update BIOS/UEFI with Samsung Utility 4) BIOS/UEFI is now fixed, install Ubuntu deleting Windows and all Ubuntu features works OK!

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem, please post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Copied OP comment here:

It was a BIOS error from Samsung. The problem was solved according to next steps.

1. Enter to BIOS/UEFI from Windows 8 installation disk.
2. On the BIOS/UEFI set hard disk to "normal" (not AHCI)
3. Install Windows 8 (no blue screen!)
4. Update BIOS/UEFI with Samsung Utility
5. BIOS/UEFI is now fixed, install Ubuntu deleting Windows and all Ubuntu features works OK!